# Is "get in game" a correct way of asking someone to get online in a video game?

Tags: word-choice, articles, phrasal-verbs

In particular, is it OK to use no article (to avoid confusion with the idiom "get in the game")? Are there any better ways to tell someone to log into the game without saying "log in"? Example: "get in game tonight to claim your rewards".

Comment: No, you need an article. Articles (or some sort of determiner) are almost always needed with singular nouns in English. If you don't like "Get in the game," how about "Join the game"?

Comment: I can see the use of "get in-game" as a parallel to "get on-line."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> get in game

You're misunderstanding the phrase. The correct parsing is:

> get ingame

Where ["ingame"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ingame) refers to:

> 1) (adj) The state of being inside of a full screen and online game.

*I am aware that UrbanDictionary isn't the most reputable of sources, but this word is very informal and relatively new, I couldn't find a better reference.*

This phrasing is very idiomatic in English (unlike the word "ingame" itself):

> I want to get drunk.
>   I want to get lucky.
>   I want you to get busy.

Similarly:

> I want you to get ingame now, we need a healer to join our party!

---

This also means that the premise of your question is flawed. "get in the game" and "get ingame" are not directly related, this is not an omission of the definite article.

Comment: You are an edit monster.

Comment: @Davo: Revising has never been a forte of mine.

Comment: In online gaming, this was in general use ten years ago, and probably still is.